# Apache Toree job progress

Tags: apache-toree

With Apache Toree one can execute arbitrary expressions on Spark. Say we want to execute some SQL query like:`sqlContext.sql(..)`

Is it possible to get a progress (like in Zeppelin) for such SQL query? Maybe Toree can provide some query metrics (like `X tasks from N are done`)?

Comment: Perhaps Spark REST API could help

Answer (score 1):

The way Apache Zeppelin use is through sc.dagScheduler.

[REST API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html) should be a better choice if can not access the SparkContext directly.

```
package org.apache.zeppelin.spark

class SparkInterpreter {
  @Override
  public int getProgress(InterpreterContext context) {
    String jobGroup = getJobGroup(context);
    int completedTasks = 0;
    int totalTasks = 0;

    DAGScheduler scheduler = sc.dagScheduler();
    if (scheduler == null) {
      return 0;
    }
    HashSet<ActiveJob> jobs = scheduler.activeJobs();
    if (jobs == null || jobs.size() == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    Iterator<ActiveJob> it = jobs.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
      ActiveJob job = it.next();
      String g = (String) job.properties().get("spark.jobGroup.id");
      if (jobGroup.equals(g)) {
        int[] progressInfo = null;
        try {
          Object finalStage = job.getClass().getMethod("finalStage").invoke(job);
          if (sparkVersion.getProgress1_0()) {
            progressInfo = getProgressFromStage_1_0x(sparkListener, finalStage);
          } else {
            progressInfo = getProgressFromStage_1_1x(sparkListener, finalStage);
          }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
            | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException
            | SecurityException e) {
          logger.error("Can't get progress info", e);
          return 0;
        }
        totalTasks += progressInfo[0];
        completedTasks += progressInfo[1];
      }
    }

    if (totalTasks == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    return completedTasks * 100 / totalTasks;
  }
}
```

Comment: what is sc.dagScheduler ?